# Delay in displaying a video stream after streaming by libavformat

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, libavformat

I am using libavformat library to stream a video at a network address like udp://127.0.0.1:1000. I use ffplay to display the received video stream at the network address. However, the video appears few second later (e.g. 5 6 seconds) at ffplay on the same machine. Do you know what is the reason?

More info:

I have written my own streaming application using libavformat. When I stream a 3sec 1080p video at 25fps, ffplay does not show anything. If I repeat streaming the same video once again, this time, ffplay starts displaying the previous streamed video as well as the current video. So, it looks like ffplay waits for a buffer to be filled up by some amount, and then displays the stream. But am I correct?

Comment: I have had better luck with mplayer -benchmark (ffplay introduces its own latency) see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide (mplayer may need a patch if you're using udp tho)

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are describing you are (at least) encoding the video stream, sending it over a network socket and then decoding it again. If you are streaming from an already compressed source, there may even be an additional video decoding stage involved.

Depending on the video format, the compression and buffering settings, your network configuration and the hardware involved, a delay of several seconds is not out of the ordinary. People watching TV channels using their live streaming services often see such delays when comparing to the over-the-air signal, and TV stations are supposedly using professional equipment for the streaming process...

You might be able to get more specific help if you mention how you are using the `libavformat` library (especially if you have written your own streaming application), the codec settings and some basics about your video stream, such as its resolution and frame rate.

Comment: Thanks. I have written my own streaming application using libavformat. When I stream a 3sec 1080p video at 25fps, ffplay does not show anything. If I repeat streaming the same video once again, this time, ffplay starts displaying the previous streamed video as well as the current video. So, it looks like ffplay waits for a buffer to be filled up by some amount, and then displays the stream. But am I correct?